# How can I filter on both a columnA value and the MAX(columnB) of a subset of that data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have the following data question that I am trying to figure out how to encapsulate in a Google Sheets formula or query:

```
Player     Game  Shots Scored
Washington  1         3
Lincoln     1         6
Roosevelt   1         4
Washington  2         3
Grant       2         1
Kennedy     2         3
```

What I am interested in doing is calculating the average shots scored as a percentage of the scoring-est player in that game. Or, in other words:

```
For a Player P:
 Return the Average of(
    For Each Distinct Game containing P (
        P.Points / Max(Points)  
    )
 )
```

For instance, the result I'm looking at, using the data above, is:

```
Player      Performance
Washington      75% [=(3/6+3/3)/2 * 100%]         
Lincoln         100%          
Roosevelt       66%               
Grant           33%       
Kennedy         100%
```

This kind of compound computation is proving remarkably hard to translate to google query language, though -- any help?

> =unique(filter(A2:C,A2:A="Washington"))

Returns all the lines for the "Washington" player, but (possibly) loses the data about the most scoring-est person in that game. Is there a way to include that row in the filter as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this via a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) created in Google Apps Script. To achieve this, follow these steps:

- In your spreadsheet, select **Tools > Script editor** to open a script bound to your file.
- Copy this function in the script editor, and save the project:

```js
function GETAVERAGES(input) {
  const games = Array.from(new Set(input.map(row => row[1]))).map(game => {
    let maxResult = Math.max(...input.filter(row => row[1] === game).map(row => row[2]));
    return [game, maxResult]; // Get max score for each game
  });  
  return Array.from(new Set(input.map(row => row[0]))).map(player => {
    let playerRows = input.filter(row => row[0] === player); // Filter rows according to player
    let percentages = playerRows.reduce((acc, row) => { // Percentage sum for current player
      let maxGame = games.find(game => game[0] === row[1])[1]; // Max score for current game   
      return acc + row[2] / maxGame; // Accumulated percentage
    }, 0);
    let average = percentages / playerRows.length; // Divide accumulated per number of games
    return [player, average]; // Return array of player name and corresponding average
  });
}
```

- Now, if you go back to your spreadsheet, you can use this function as if you were using a regular sheets formula. You just have to provide the appropriate range as an argument (in this case `A2:C7`), as you can see here:

[image]

#### Reference:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)